# Customizing autocite with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am getting some unexpected output with `biblatex`. In the following MWE I expect to get the same thing with `\footcites` and `\autocites`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]{A}{B}{\multicitedelim}{}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\footcite}{\multicitedelim}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}{\footcite}{\footcites}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\footcite{aksin}
\autocite{aksin}
\footcites{aksin}{aksin}
\autocites{aksin}{aksin}
\end{document}
```

If I add `\letcs\autocites{blx@macite@footnote}` then `\footcites` and `\autocites` give me the same output. I feel like I am missing something about how `autocite` works.

Further, if I change the `biblatex` package options to `autocite=myfootnote` and use `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{myfootnote}{\footcite}{\footcites}` I get errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand` etc. seems to be designed for use in citation style files. I think it will not work properly like this because it is basically too late. It needs to be there as `biblatex` loads in a `.cbx`. (But I'm by no means sure about this.)

Comment: These `\Declare...CiteCommand` macros do seem to be intended to be used in a `.cbx` file, and as cfr suspects might not be usable in the actual document (I could not find anything explicit about that in the bibliography, but it seems to hint at/point in that general direction). In some cases it might be desirable to make these changes in the document itself though (and not via a `.cbx` file), so you might want to bring this issue up in the [`biblatex` bugtracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand a little...

Is this the expected output?

[image: autocite=myfootnote]

If so, I think you just need to put the relevant commands in a config file rather than including them in your preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex.cfg}% include commands which biblatex expects to find in e.g. .cbx files here and put the file somewhere tex will find it
    \ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}
    \DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]{A}{B}{\multicitedelim}{}
    \DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\footcite}{\multicitedelim}
    \DeclareAutoCiteCommand{myfootnote}{\footcite}{\footcites}
    \endinput
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[autocite=myfootnote]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\footcite{aksin}
\autocite{aksin}
\footcites{aksin}{aksin}
\autocites{aksin}{aksin}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that is the expected output. I am surprised that I cannot use them in the document body.

Comment: @StrongBad I think that saying `autocite=myfootnote` requires that `myfootnote` be defined. However, to define it, you obviously need the commands from `biblatex`. So, timing-wise, the only way to make that work is to have `biblatex` read the definition in another file *before* it processes the `autocite=myfootnote` option, and that rules out including the definition in the document itself. I suspect something similar is happening with the customisation of `footnote` since that is only happening *after* `autocite=footnote` is processed. So probably you could customise that in a config file.