# How to combine repeated bibliography entries when using footcite?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, footnotes, footcite

If I cite the same source several times consecutively, it produces a bibliography list consisting of identical items:

> ---
>
> 1. author, title
> 2. author, title

```
\begin{filecontents}{database.bib}
@Misc{key,
    author      = {author},
    title       = {title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[autocite=footnote,style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\bibliography{database.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item one point\autocite{key}
\item another one\autocite{key}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

How do I compress the list in the footnote to look like this:

> ---
>
> 1,2 author, title

Comment: Here a link about [how to accept an answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a solution that does not compress the list of footnote but prints the footnote only once per page.

The idea is to redefine a cite command called `\footcite`. Then, in order to but accepted by the `autocite` option of biblatex, I put it into a `biblatex.cfg` file according to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159192/customizing-autocite-with-biblatex) and name it `myfootnote`.

And the `\footcite`, when called, is always creating a `\footnotemark` using the label number of the key. Then, according to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58009/biblatex-tricks-with-repeated-citations-in-footnotes), if the `\footcite` is called for the first time on this page, it also create a `\footnotetext`.

Here is the resulting MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex.cfg}
    \ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}
    \DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}%
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}% 
    {%
        %   \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}% Switch to footnote with numbers
        \footnotemark[\thefield{labelnumber}]% Add the mark corresponding to the number entry% 
        \iffirstonpage{
            \footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{% Add the footnote text with same number entry.
                %\printfield{labelnumber}
                \printnames{labelname}% The name 
                \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}% separator
                \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}% The title
                \setunit{\addperiod\space}% separator
                \printfield{year}% The year
        }
        }{}% if not first on page
        %   \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}% Switch back to footnote with letters.
    }%
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
    \DeclareAutoCiteCommand{myfootnote}{\footcite}{\footcite}
    \endinput
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{database.bib}
    @Misc{key,
        author      = {author},
        title       = {title},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[autocite=myfootnote, style=numeric, pagetracker=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{database.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item one point\autocite{key}
    \item another one\autocite{key}
\end{itemize}
\newpage
\begin{itemize}
    \item one point\autocite{key}
    \item another one\autocite{key}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

One possible improvement that I don't know how to do, would be the make this hack compatible with other bibstyles. Indeed, if someone switch style to `alphabetic` for example, would get compilation error: `missing number`; since the `footnotemark` will not received a number but a text given by `\thefield{labelnumber}`.

Comment: And I was hoping that I simply missed some package option to do this

Comment: A simplier option is to define your command (like myfootcite) and use it instead of `\autocite`. Otherwise, I don't know how to compress the footnote.